# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'coloredButton' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, react-native, undefined

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'coloredButton' of undefined, js engine: hermes

I have installed: `npm install react-native-material-kit` and other necessary libraries

How can I fix the error?

code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import { MKTextField, MKColor, MKButton } from 'react-native-material-kit';
import * as actions from '../actions';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    form: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 50,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingRight: 20,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    fieldStyles: {
        height: 40,
        color: MKColor.Orange,
    },
    addButton: {
        marginTop: 20,
    },
});
const AddButton = MKButton.coloredButton()
    .withText('ADD')
    .build();

class AddPerson extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Icon name={'add-user'} size={30} color={tintColor} />
        )
    )
}
```